# separate data from a api

Tags: php, json, api, decode

we are trying to make a website for our class, here you can see important news, the class schedule, homework schedule and a contact page for tips and bugs...

So, we want to have the schedule always up to date and a class mate made a api to get the schedule-data from our school site. but now we have an issue... he don't want to help us anymore!!! -,-

**here is the question?**
The schedule is echo in a table but it stand next to eachother, because the api  only separate the days including the lesson. but we want the lesson seperate from the day! and echo the table below each other..

Is there anyone who want to help me / Us out???
[Link for a live previeuw how its now!](http://www.reduankurtaj.eu/appV2/rooster.php)

```
<?php

$apis = array('verandermij');

if (!isset($_GET['afdeling'])) //school sector
{
    echo "FOUTCODE 1"; //Wrongcode
    exit;
}

if (!isset($_GET['klas'])) // class
{
    echo "FOUTCODE 2"; //Wrongcode
    exit;
}

if (!isset($_GET['api']))
{
    echo "FOUTCODE 3"; //Wrongcode
    exit;
}

$apigeldig = false;
foreach ($apis as $api)
{ 
    if ($api == $_GET['api'])
    {
        $apigeldig = true;
    }
}

if ($apigeldig == false)
{
    echo "FOUTCODE 4"; //Wrongcode
    exit;
}

$afdeling = $_GET['afdeling'];
$klas = $_GET['klas'];

// get the class data
$url = "https://rooster.rocfriesepoort.nl/emmeloord.aspx?group=" . $afdeling . "&specs=" . $klas . "&a=1";
$content = file_get_contents($url);

// little bit cleaning
$content = explode("<div class=header>Rooster</div>", $content);
$content = $content[1];

// Splits dagen
$raw_dagen = explode("<td valign=top style='background-color: #e5e5e5'>", $content); //Raw_Days
$clean_dagen = array(); // Clean_Days

$dagen = array( //Days
    $raw_dagen[1],
    $raw_dagen[2],
    $raw_dagen[3],
    $raw_dagen[4],
    $raw_dagen[5]
);

// Beginnen met sorteren
$opgeschoond = array(); //Cleand

$stoploop = false;
foreach ($dagen as $dag) //Days as Day
{
    $tmp = explode("</div>", $dag);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($tmp as $item)
    {
        if ($stoploop == true) { $i++; continue; }
        if ($tmp[$i] == null) { $i++; continue; }
        $tmp[$i] = str_replace("<div class='dagHeader'>", "", $tmp[$i]);
        $tmp[$i] = str_replace("<div class=tablecell3>", "VRIJ", $tmp[$i]);
        $tmp[$i] = str_replace("<div class=tablecell1>", "", $tmp[$i]);
        $tmp[$i] = str_replace("<div class=tablecell2>", "", $tmp[$i]);
        $tmp[$i] = str_replace('<br style="clear:both"></br><br><br><div id=footer style="width:95%;">&copy; ROC Friese Poort 2015 - ', "", $tmp[$i]);
        $tmp[$i] = str_replace("<a href='javascript:void(0)'". ' onclick="Disclaimer' . "('500','500','YES')" . '" title=' . "'Disclaimer'>", "", $tmp[$i]);

        if ($tmp[$i] == "</td>")
        {
            $tmp[$i] = "DAG EINDE";
        }
        if ($tmp[$i] == "</td></table>")
        {
            $tmp[$i] = "DAG EINDE";
            unset($tmp[$i + 1]);
            unset($tmp[$i + 2]);
            unset($tmp[$i + 3]);
            unset($tmp[$i + 4]);
            unset($tmp[$i + 5]);
            unset($tmp[$i + 6]);
            $stoploop = true;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    array_push($opgeschoond, $tmp);
}

print(json_encode($opgeschoond));
```

?>

this we use the echo the data!!!!!

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <?php
                foreach ($maandag as $lesuur)
                {
                    print("<td>");
                        print($lesuur);
                    print("</td>");
                }

            ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php
                foreach ($dinsdag as $lesuur)
                {
                    print("<td id='oneven'>");
                        print($lesuur);
                    print("</td>");
                }

            ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php
                foreach ($woensdag as $lesuur)
                {
                    print("<td>");
                        print($lesuur);
                    print("</td>");
                }

            ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php
                foreach ($donderdag as $lesuur)
                {
                    print("<td id='oneven'>");
                        print($lesuur);
                    print("</td>");
                }

            ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php
                foreach ($vrijdag as $lesuur)
                {
                    print("<td>");
                        print($lesuur);
                    print("</td>");
                }

            ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

link for the raw data: [enter link description here](http://amandovledder.eu/api.php?afdeling=EEIT&klas=ICTOM1A&api=rstrapp)

```
[["Maandag 09-11-2015","MTM
```

Nederlands
C2.02
","MTM
Nederlands
A2.08
","VRIJ","KAS
Wiskunde
B2.02
","KSR
SLB
A2.07
","DAG EINDE"],["Dinsdag 10-11-2015","VRIJ","CRL
Database techn.
A2.07
","CRL
Database techn.
A2.07
","CRL
CMS
A2.07
","VRIJ","CRL
CMS
A2.07
","CRL
Webservers
A2.07
","CRL
Webservers
A2.07
","DAG EINDE"],["Woensdag 11-11-2015","VRIJ","VRIJ","KSR
Java Script
A2.07
","KSR
Java Script
A2.07
","VRIJ","VRIJ","VSS
Routeplanner
B2.04
","VSS
LevO
B2.04
","VSS
LLB
B2.04
","DAG EINDE"],["Donderdag 12-11-2015","VRIJ","KRJ
Project
A2.07
","KRJ
Project
A2.07
","KRJ
Project
A2.07
","VRIJ","KSR
Scrum
A2.07
","GFO
Rekenen
B2.01
","KSR
Scrum
A2.07
","DAG EINDE"],["Vrijdag 13-11-2015","ZAA
Engels
B2.03
","ZAA
Engels
B2.06a
","KRJ
Project
A2.07
","KRJ
Project
A2.07
","VRIJ","KSR
SLB
A2.07
","GFO
Rekenen
B2.06
","DAG EINDE"]]

thanks for helping me, a beginner (a)

Comment: Can you post the full raw results you get from the api url?

Comment: @Alderin the link and raw_data are in my question!

Comment: The raw data is easy to read on the hyperlink i gave you guys!!! i gave you  2, one example of the webpage in the table, and 1 where it is cleaned and readable!!! so i don't understand your problem?? @RyanVincent

Answer (score 0):

The data returned from the 'api' is a two dimensional array, with the second dimension variable width, but the first entry is the day. `data[0][0] = "Maandag 09-11-2015";`.

If I understand correctly, what you want is something like this:

```
$apidata = file_get_contents($apiurl);
$data = json_decode($apidata, true);

$maandag = array_slice($data[0],1)
$dinsdag = array_slice($data[1],1)
$woensdag = array_slice($data[2],1)
$donderdag = array_slice($data[3],1)
$vrijdag = array_slice($data[4],1)
```

Then your echo from above will work, the day names removed from the arrays (though also the dates).

Once in this form, building a table for the days is relatively simple (though I'm sure others will have a cleaner way to do it):

```
<?php
$longest = 0;
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
  if($data[$i].count()>$longest) $longest=$data[$i].count();
}
$longest--; // we removed one entry already
?>
<table>
<tr><th>Maandag</th><th>Dinsdag</th><th>Woensdag</th><th>Donderdag</th><th>Vrijdag</th></tr>
<?php
for($i=0;$i<$longest;$i++) {
  print "<tr><td>{$maandag[$i]}</td><td>{$dinsdag[$i]}</td><td>{$woensdag[$i]}</td><td>{$donderdag[$i]}</td><td>{$vrijdag[$i]}</td></tr>\n";
}
?>
</table>
```

That should have you set. There may be runtime errors attempting to access the array entries of the shorter days before the longest day is finished, but you can fix that with another loop adding empty strings.

Comment: yeah almost!!! the lesson stand next to each other but i want them down..     
Like:
Maandag | dinsdag | woensdag | 
#lesson 1 | #lesson 1 | #lesson 1 |
#lesson 2 |#lesson 2 | #lesson 2 |

etc...

Comment: got these errors :(

Notice: Use of undefined constant length - assumed 'length' in /home/reduaqi158/domains/reduankurtaj.eu/public_html/appV2/rooster.php on line 65

Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/reduaqi158/domains/reduankurtaj.eu/public_html/appV2/rooster.php on line 65

Comment: Ah, the hazards of switching between languages. In php, it's .count().